# How to write cleaner that js code: return after error message

Tags: javascript

I have a code block like this:

```
var someFunction = function() {

  // some code

  if(someCondition) {
    NotificationService.error("errorMessage");
    return;
  }

  // some code
}
```

The error function of NotificationService returns nothing, just prints error message on the screen. someFunction method also returns nothing. If I catch an error by checking some different conditions, I don't want to continue function and always using same code block is annoyed. How can i avoid repeating this block:

```
NotificationService.error("errorMessage");
return;
```

Comment: You should use `throw` and error objects. These can then be used with `try..catch` to give actual error handling.

Comment: That a terrible way to ask a question, it makes no sense, please fix the grammar.

Comment: If this can be written "cleaner" (or do you actually mean shorter?), depends on the conditions and the error messages, are they different on every condition? If it's not possible to put more conditions together, or use some variables to produce an index of an error message, there's not much you can do.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you mean like this? :     var someFunction = function() {

        try {
       // some code
 
          if(someCondition) throw "errorMessage";
   
       // some code
     } catch(err) {
          NotificationService.error(err);
        }

    }
I think this is better. Thanks.